# Add values from array of objects in dropdown and then update values in text input React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

just trying to loop over an array of objects and then display them in a dropdown. I have that part down fine. The part I am struggling with is then showing a text input when you select a value in the dropdown that is tied to that value. What I want to do then is a PUT request to update the values in the array of objects if they are updated. This is in React just using hooks. Here is what I have:

```
const people = [ 
      {id: 1, name: "Jason"}, 
      {id: 2, name: "Steve"}, 
      {id: 3, name: "Susan"}
]

const [activePerson, setActivePerson] = useState(null);
const [updatedPerson, setUpdatedPerson] = useState(null);

const handlePersonChange = event => {
   setActivePerson(event.target.value);
};

 const updatePerson = (id, newValue) => {
  const matchedPerson = people.find(
    person => person.id === id
  );

  const newPeople = [...people];

  newPeople[matchedPerson].name = newValue;

  setUpdatedPerson(newPeople);
};

<select 
  name="person" 
  value={activePerson} 
  onChange={handlePersonChange}
>
{people.map(person => (
  <option 
   key={person.id} 
   value={person.name}
  >
   {person.name}
  </option>
 ))}
</select>

{activePerson !== null && (

<label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" value={activePerson} onChange={e => { 
  updatePerson(activePerson.id, e.target.value)}
)}
```

One more thing of note. I am getting the people array from a GET Request. I am then going to update this array with the new values with a PUT request via the Fetch API.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The first thing you need to fix is the `updatePerson` method. Your function takes two parameters but you're sending just one, so the `id` parameter inside your function is actually the `newValue`. To fix this you should have your active person saved in a state variable, and then use it inside `updatePerson`.

Side note: making a PUT request every time the user changes the string is not a very good idea and would cause big performance issues, I'd suggest you add a button to update the person name once the user is done typing.

Comment: @ManuelEsperon, oh my gosh. I have no idea how I missed that. Thanks for pointing that out. Also, totally agree about the button. That would be terrible for performance. Thanks for the help!